# Mat Table into mat dialog

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello I'm trying to put a mat-table inside a mat dialog content but it doesn't show me the data.

This is the `dialog-content.html`

```
<mat-dialog-content class="pb-3" *ngIf="action == 'Update';">
<form #userForm="ngForm">
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource2" class="table employee-list no-wrap">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="employee_view">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Employee View</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
          <!-- {{element.name}} -->
          <input type="text" value="{{element.employee_view}}">
          <mat-checkbox [disabled]="true" color="primary" [checked]="row.employee_view" (change)="checkCheckBoxvalue($event,row.perfilid, employee_view_name)"></mat-checkbox>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns2"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns2;"></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And this is the `component.ts`

```
  dataSource2 = new MatTableDataSource<any>();
  displayedColumns2: string[] = ['name', 'employee_view'];

  constructor(
      public datePipe: DatePipe,
      public apiSvc: ProfileService,
      public snackBar: MatSnackBar,
      public translate: TranslateService,
      public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ProfileDialogContent>,
      // @Optional() is used to prevent error if no data is passed
      @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: Profile) {
      this.local_data = { ...data };
      console.log(this.local_data);
      
      this.action = this.local_data.action;
      this.dataSource2.data = this.local_data;
      console.log(this.dataSource2);
  }
```

And shows me this when I click the pencil button for update

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTfiO.png)

If it helps, here is an image of the array that I pass to the dataSource

[array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpfHs.png)

Comment: And what your console logs outputs? What does your data look like?

Comment: You "array" image shows an Object, not an array. That could be the problem.

Comment: Oh men... now that you said it I think that's the problem, I need that `this.local_data` be an object but I'll look the way that pass to an array, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasource needs to be an array. You have passed an object. Just wrap your data into an array when you pass it to the datasource and that should solve your issue.

```
this.dataSource2.data = [this.local_data];
```

Comment: Yes, that's actually what I did, anyways thank you so much